# Отображение фона блока

Tags: html, css

Не отображается фон блока:

```
<html>
 <head>
    <title>
        Repairing
    </title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style/style.css" />
 </head>
 <body>
   <div class="header">
   </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

Но если поменять `.header` на `body`, то все нормально.

```
.header {
 background-image: url(images/bg1.jpg);
 background-size: 1280px 750px;
 background-color: 51ff44;
}
```

В чем моя ошибка?

Comment: `background-image: url('../images/bg1.jpg');`

Comment: А высота .header какая?

Comment: Она ведь не задана

Comment: @MaRK вот вот, поэтому и фон не видно, т.к. высота .header - 0 пикселей, что, по сути, означает, что .header "невидим"

Comment: @Cheg Спасибо, помогло. Второй раз спасаешь меня из-зи моей невнимательности)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Изначально div имеет высоту 0, поэтому фона не видно. Поменяйте размер div'а

Comment: разве ширина div будет равна 0?

Comment: уж точно ширина не 0 изначально

Comment: div это блочный элемент, поэтому его ширина равна 100%

Comment: на счет 100% сомневаюсь, скорее всего там что то другое потому-что он работает аналогично `box-sizing:border-box; width:100%;`